# getlantern / systray(Golang) is working on windows vs code but not in Macos

Tags: macos, go, system-tray

I was developing a Golang application on Windows using the getlantern/systray library to implement a system tray functionality. Upon switching to a Mac for development, I encountered an error. Is there a solution to resolve this issue?

```
func main() {

    onExit := func() {
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    go func() {
        systray.Run(onReady, onExit)
    }()
```

```
func onReady() {
    systray.SetIcon(iconData)
    systray.SetTitle("Connectapp")
    systray.SetTooltip("Connectapp")
    mQuit := systray.AddMenuItem("Quit", "Quit the whole app")

    go func() {
        <-mQuit.ClickedCh
        systray.Quit()
    }()
}
```

When running 'go build' in Visual Studio Code on Windows, I encountered no errors. However, when working on macOS in Visual Studio Code, an error occurred, as shown below:

```
# github.com/getlantern/systray
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:78:2: undefined: nativeLoop
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:106:2: undefined: registerSystray
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:111:14: undefined: quit
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:136:2: undefined: addSeparator
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:190:2: undefined: hideMenuItem
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:195:2: undefined: showMenuItem
../../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/getlantern/systray@v1.2.2/systray.go:220:2: undefined: addOrUpdateMenuItem
```

Comment: i am able to run this code, on terminal on mac.

Comment: i am also able to run it older version of mac but when i try it in m2 it showing the above problem!!

Comment: have you tried installing rosetta2 `https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211861`

Comment: When working in VSCode on a Mac, I only run the "go build" command to compile my Go code. But it shows error so the app is not generated